# What can I do about a rental house that shakes in the wind?

Tags: house

My house is new. I rent. It was built in the past yr.

We have 2 stories up plus basement. The back of our home is completely flat and the backyard is kinda big an open since it is a new subdivision. Our house is a stand alone type so no others are connected. We have 4 bedrooms and 2 baths on the second(top) floor.

When it gets windy, it’s so bad the windows bow inwards and at night if I sit on the bed I can feel it swaying. Our bed is against the back wall of the house but I’ve noticed it even on the side wall too. It’s bad. Like it feel a cross between a water bed and if someone was underneath trying to play games making waves with the mattress.

We’ve been here a year and this is the worst it’s been. It makes me nervous as it doesn’t only happen in the master bedroom but the entire upstairs. I feel like if the wind was bad enough the walls may cave in. I’m almost 30 and have lived in many places most of which were multi level homes with bedrooms on top floors and never have I encountered this.

What can I do? I can’t plant trees nor plan on being here long enough to see them grow. Nor can I install a high enough fence. It would have to be easily 20ft high to make any impact on winds. Is this a structural issue?

Comment: What country do you live? ... the answer can vary widely. In the US, there are local agencies that can be contacted (i.e. building inspectors), which can also vary by state.

Comment: Is this a new house by itself in the middle of old houses or one of many nearly identical new houses? If it is one of many nearly identical new houses (a typical new subdivision) then **talk to your neighbors** to find out if they have similar problems.

Comment: Could you provide more information that is objective, rather than subjective, about the motion?  For example, to determine the extent to which walls are moving, you  could hang a washer or nut on a string attached to a curtain rod and long enough to reach the floor, and measure the deviation with a ruler.  For the floor, place a carpenter's level or a bowl of water where it responds to floor movement and mark the high and low points on one side of the bowl.  Put a straight edge like a yardstick (meter stick) against the window to gauge the wind bow.

Comment: Plant Poplars or Cottonwood trees. They grow upwards of 5 ft per year. Thuja Arborvitae don't grow quite as fast, but they're much nicer. For Poplar or Cottonwood, I'd plant nicer, slow growing trees also so that the fast growers can be chopped down when they get too big.

Comment: `I rent`. **Contact the landlord immediately**. There is _nothing_ you can do to impact the structure without the landlord's permission. If the house is only ~1 year old, there may be a builder's warranty that the landlord could invoke to get the builders back out to address issues. To specifically address the question, I've seen houses around me that had foam board as external sheathing instead of plywood/OSB. I'd imagine they'd do exactly the same thing you're describing. They do this because it's cheaper... :(

Comment: @popham: ... And the poplars/aspens *will* get too big. Their pattern is to keep growing rapidly upward until they get too tall for their roots and fall over. I still sorta wish I'd hired a portable sawmill to reduce mine to boards; poplar isn't a very pretty wood and it moves a lot with humidity, but it's perfectly reasonable as a secondary wood and there was a lot of it. I got scared off by just how much water was pouring out after it was cut; should have expected that )

Comment: Poplar has a very dense grain and is great for making things that will be painted, @keshlam. ;)

Comment: Of course. since we have been reminded that this is a rental, planting trees may not be a permitted option

Comment: @FreeMan, "Thermo-Ply" instantly came to mind when I was reading this. The windows, though, make it seem like it's just high wind.

Answer (score 1):

Your rental is almost certainly not going to fall over. Even pathetically built structures are surprisingly resilient.

Contact your landlord with as many concrete details as you can be bothered to provide. It’s their problem. (And maybe the problem of the builder as well.)

If it’s something you can’t live with, make an orderly plan for moving. While this would certainly be a law stack question, I doubt that you’d get away with breaking a lease unilaterally because the house was flimsy.